# Starting a new Activity containing a new Fragment

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity

**How do I start a new Activity when a button is clicked and have that activity contain and start  a new Fragment?**

Comment: Please elaborate more on what you want to achieve, which steps you already have taken, and what problem you encounter.

Comment: The scenario is that I have a Main Activity and in that Activity there are 4 buttons each having a unique task to perform. Now, what I'm trying is when I click a button a new Activity opens and in that new Activity I want open a Fragment corresponding to the button I clicked before. Example: In Main Activity button1 opens the  new Activity(secondActivity)  containing Fragment1, button2 opens the secondActivity containing Fragment2 and so on.